# Formally proving that $S^{n-1} \subset D^n$ glued to $D^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following statement: Let $\varphi:S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{D}^n, x\mapsto x$. Show that $\mathbb{D}^n \cup_\varphi \mathbb{D}^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$

I can see intuitively why this works, for example when $n=2$ we are gluing two copies of the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the boundary of the two disks are identified with each other, and all the other points being single point equivalence classes. I see this geometrically giving us the upper hemisphere, since we can only glue the boundaries together and all other points must be distinct. We can then easily define a homeomorphism from this hemisphere to the whole sphere.

I am however not sure how to prove this formally.

Comment: For clarification, can you also mention what do you mean by $\cup_\varphi$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh That is the adjunction space, meaning that two spaces are glued together via an equivalence relation defined by the map $\varphi$, namely $x\sim\varphi(x)$.